# jqGrid searchOperators not showing toolbar filter

Tags: python, jqgrid

I followed the example on http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html under **"Searching | Toolbar with Operators"**, with the sample code below.

The code (as far as I can tell), is identical to the jqGrid sample code given, with the exception of the data source.

The problem is that I am unable to make the Toolbar Filter **Operators** to show up.
The Filter Toolbar itself does exist and functions as expected.

The code below is self sufficient and can be loaded in a browser from a local file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.0.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.0.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.0.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myData = [
                {item_id:"1", item:"test",  item_cd:"note"   },
                {item_id:"2", item:"test2", item_cd:"note2"  },
                {item_id:"3", item:"test3", item_cd:"note3"  },
                {item_id:"4", item:"test4", item_cd:"note4"  },
                {item_id:"5", item:"test5", item_cd:"note5"  },
                {item_id:"6", item:"test6", item_cd:"note6"  },
                {item_id:"7", item:"test7", item_cd:"note7"  },
                {item_id:"8", item:"test8", item_cd:"note8"  },
                {item_id:"9", item:"test9", item_cd:"note9"  },
                {item_id:"10",item:"test10",item_cd:"note10" },
                {item_id:"11",item:"test11",item_cd:"note11" },
                {item_id:"12",item:"test12",item_cd:"note12" }
            ],

        myGrid = $("#list451");

        myGrid.jqGrid({
            datatype:'local',
            data: myData,
            height: 255,
            width: 600,
            colNames:['Index','Name', 'Code'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'item_id',index:'item_id', width:65,  sorttype:'integer', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','le','lt','gt','ge']}},
                {name:'item',index:'item', width:150, sorttype:'string', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}},
                {name:'item_cd',index:'item_cd', width:100}
            ],
            rowNum:50,
            rowTotal: 200,
            rowList : [20,30,50],
            loadonce:true,
            //mtype: "GET",
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            gridview: true,
            pager: '#pager451',
            sortname: 'item_id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Loading data from server at once"
        });
        myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch : "cn"});
        jQuery("#list451").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators : true});
    });
</script>
```

The HTML code:

> ```
> <table id="list451"><tr><td/></tr></table>
> <div id="pager451"></div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your error exist because you use **two** separate calls of `filterToolbar` instead of usage **one** call with additional option `searchOperators: true`:

```js
myGrid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
    searchOperators: true,
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter: false,
    defaultSearch: "cn"
});
```

I would recommend you additionally remove `index` properties from all `colModel` items. I suppose that you changed you original code which uses `datatype: "json"` to `datatype: "local"` to demonstrate the problem only. You use `loadonce: true` so the values of `index` properties must be the same as the values of `name` property. So removing of `index` properties will be the best choice.

Comment: I combined the two separate **filterToolbar** as advised, but still not getting the filter operators to show up. 
(I indeed use JSON in real life, the local is judt to demo the problem).

Comment: Are you sure that you use the last version of jqGrid? Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RaphaelE.htm). It displays the searching operation in the toolbar.

Comment: For me it doesn't work in Jqgrid 4.4.4 and works fine in the latest Jqgrid 4.5.2

Comment: @Alex: `searchOperators: true` option can't work in jqGrid 4.4.4 because the feature was introduced in 4.5.0.